# Better way to lay out an evenly spaced grid on Android Wear

Tags: android, layout, wear-os

I am laying out a grid of four slight-differently sized ImageViews in an Android Wear Activity, and want an evenly spaced grid with the ImageViews scaled to fit inside the grid cells.

I have done this with nested Linear Layouts, including a buffer column at either end to push the cells more into the middle (to avoid the clipping on the edges of a round watch) and a buffer zone at the bottom to push the cells above the "chin" on certain round watches. This works ok, but I generally try to avoid nested Linear Layouts. Is there a better way?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/goal_strip"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/goal_actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_goal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:scaleX="0.8"
            android:scaleY="0.8"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/minus_light"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_goal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_white_24dp"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yellow_card"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/yellow_card"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/red_card"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/red_card"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the desired end result:[image]

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't think that having a `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout` is that bad. But you might want to consider using margins or padding instead of those extra `FrameLayouts`.

Comment: I really don't like the FrameLayouts, but couldn't see any other way to do a % margin. The trouble is that watch faces have a wide range of sizes, and 40dp can look great on a big watch and absolutely cramp the icons on a small watch. But I'm open to ideas.

Comment: I would define the margin in dimens.xml, and use the emulator to find the right value for each density bucket. It's a bit more work but a better solution in my opinion.